# using protocol app getting crashed ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, protocols, uipopovercontroller

I have application where i have two view controllers my first view and second view controller is in uipopovercontroller. i want value of second view controller in first view for that i have created protocol. here is my code.
    #import 
    #import "SearchPopoverController.h"
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<PassSearchValueDelegate>{
AppDelegate *appDelegate;

SearchPopoverController *popSearch;

IBOutlet UILabel *lblAdd;
}

-(IBAction)showpop:(id)sender;
@end


#import "ViewController.h"

// my ViewController.m file code

-(void) getLocationList:(NSString *)strSearch{
lblAdd.text = strSearch;
}
-(IBAction)showpop:(id)sender{
if(![appDelegate.delObjSearchPopoverCon isPopoverVisible]){
    SearchPopoverController *popser = [[SearchPopoverController alloc] init];
    popSearch = popser;
    [popSearch setDelegate:self];

    appDelegate.delObjSearchPopoverCon = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popSearch] ;

    [appDelegate.delObjSearchPopoverCon setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(400 , 150)];
    [appDelegate.delObjSearchPopoverCon presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


}
```

}

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@protocol PassSearchValueDelegate 
@required
-(void) getLocationList:(NSString *)strSearch;
@end
@interface SearchPopoverController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
IBOutlet UITextField *txtSearchAdd;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblSearchAdd;

id<PassSearchValueDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (retain) id _delegate;
@end


//  my SearchPopoverController.m file code

-(IBAction)btnDoneSearch_clicked:(id)sender{

NSString *strAdd = [txtSearchAdd.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
strAdd = [strAdd stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[appDelegate.delObjSearchPopoverCon dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

if (strAdd != nil || strAdd.length != 0) {
    [_delegate getLocationList:strAdd];
}
}
```

i am getting warning at this line.

```
[popSearch setDelegate:self];
```

and app getting crashed very next line.

Please help me for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id<PassSearchValueDelegate> _delegate;
// ...
@property (retain) id _delegate;
```

Your property should be named just `delegate` and maybe synthesized to use the `_delegate` instance variable. You should also specify the protocol on the property type.

Additionally, delegates should be `assign` (or `weak` under ARC) properties.

Answer (score 0):

rename `_delegate` to `delegate`
You will need to change

```
@property (retain) id delegate;
```

to

```
@property (assign) id<PassSearchValueDelegate> delegate;
```

Also in `PassSearchValueDelegate.m` add

```
@implementation PassSearchValueDelegate //After this 
@synthesize delegate; //add this
```

Comment: Shouldnt be using a retained property for a delegate. Should be assign or weak.

Comment: yes you are right, i just copied and pasted it, i wil update the answer